# Shouldn’t these HSAB questions be considered duplicates of each other?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

In the aftermath of the retagging event, there were three questions on the HSAB theory that were retagged. They are all rather bad and somehow cross-relate to each other. The questions I’m talking about are:

- [Hard-hard and soft-soft acid/base interactions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/35454)
- [Hardness and softness are terms used to describe which aspect of acidic behaviour?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10273)
- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37860

(I didn’t do a search to see if there are any more (and hopefully better) questions out there that we could link these to.)

I’m really not sure how I would want to deal with them; whether I want to vote to close, vote for two to be dupes of the third or just downvote and ignore … Or maybe write up a canonical (better) question/answer combination that we could then link these as dupes to.

Suggestions?

Comment: Now I know at least what HSAB means. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, the [first](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/35454) is a duplicate of the [second question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10273).

The [third question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37860) is a little bit different, as it might not be specifically about the principles of HSAB stuff, but needs to be answered with it. So for the third question, I would think of commenting, that the second question has an answer about HSAB and could be used to get some informations about the system in principle.